# android - google SSO chooser - Use another account option not giving callback

Tags: android, firebase, google-api-client, google-authentication

[image]

here are the steps to reproduce the issue:

1. click on google signin Button.
2. choose "use another account"
3. sign in with the new account and this should bring you back to the app.
4. app only shows dark overlay and consent form or callback(to onActivityResult) is not working.

then if i touch the screen the dark overlay goes away, at this time if i press the google button again it automatically logs me in with the account. I tried a few apps like stackoverflow,traveloka, airBNB, my own simple app with a google SSO button and glassdoor,lazada, etc and a few others and all of them give an error after getting to option 3.

I thought perhaps it was the [oauth consent form]:
[image]

i filled it out but im only requesting email as a google SSO options.  so i filled out the form but nothing after waiting a while.

if you want to see my full code, its pretty standard google SSO button [and its here](https://bitbucket.org/j2emanue/weathermap):
the class is called LoginFragment.kt

but let me post the class here that handles the login:

```
    import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.*
import android.widget.Toast
import com.github.ajalt.timberkt.Timber
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import example.org.weathermap.R
import example.org.weathermap.frameworks.bus.events.LoginSuccessEvent
import example.org.weathermap.presentation.view.application.WeatherApplication
import example.org.weathermap.presentation.view.base.BaseMvpFragment
import example.org.weathermap.presentation.contracts.authentication.AuthenticationView.LoginView
import example.org.weathermap.presentation.presenters.weather.LoginPresenter
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.login_fragment.*
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus
import javax.inject.Inject


class LoginFragment : BaseMvpFragment<LoginView, LoginPresenter>(), LoginView {

    @Inject
    lateinit var mPresenter: LoginPresenter

    @Inject
    lateinit var mAuth: FirebaseAuth

    private var mGoogleApiClient: GoogleApiClient? = null

    @Inject
    lateinit var bus: EventBus

    override fun createPresenter(): LoginPresenter {
        return mPresenter
    }

    override fun onDestroyView() {
        super.onDestroyView()
        mGoogleApiClient?.let { client ->
            when (client.isConnected) {
                true -> activity?.let {
                    client.stopAutoManage(it)
                    client.disconnect()
                }
                false -> {
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_fragment, container, false)
        (activity!!.applicationContext as WeatherApplication).appComponent.inject(this)
        setHasOptionsMenu(true)
        return rootView
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        initView()

    }

    override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu?, inflater: MenuInflater?) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater)
        menu?.clear()
    }

    private fun initView() {
        // Configure Google Sign In
        val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build()

        activity?.let {
            mGoogleApiClient = GoogleApiClient.Builder(it).enableAutoManage(it, { Toast.makeText(activity, "login error", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show() })
                    ?.addApi(Auth.GOOGLE_SIGN_IN_API, gso)
                    ?.build()
        }
        googleBtn.setOnClickListener { presenter.doSignIn() }
    }

    override fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(mGoogleApiClient)
        startActivityForResult(signInIntent, RC_SIGN_IN)
    }

    companion object {
        const val RC_SIGN_IN = 1
        fun newInstance(b: Bundle?): LoginFragment {
            val frag = LoginFragment()
            frag.arguments = b ?: Bundle()
            return frag
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            val task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                val account = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
                presenter.doFirebaseAuthWithGoogle(account)
            } catch (e: ApiException) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Timber.e { "Google sign in failed" }
                Toast.makeText(activity, R.string.login_failed, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
            }

        }
    }

    override fun firebaseAuthWithGoogle(acct: GoogleSignInAccount?) {
        showLoading(true)
        val credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct?.idToken, null)
        activity?.let {
            mAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(it, {
                        showLoading(false)
                        when (it.isSuccessful) {
                            true -> {
                                bus.post(LoginSuccessEvent())
                            }
                            else -> {
                                Toast.makeText(activity, getString(R.string.login_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }
                        }
                    })
        }
    }
}
```

what am i doing wrong ? is it a google bug ? i'd even settle for a way to disable this option on the chooser if possible at this point.

my tests where done on api 24

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from firebase ui team - https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/issues/1297 . i see that this is a known issue and will be fixed in next google play services release.